# error when try to compile omnet 4.2

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, omnet++

I am trying to install omnetpp 4.2 (can't install the new version). Anyway, running ./configure reports no errors or warnings, but when I run make I get the following:

```
make MODE=release
***** Configuration: MODE=release, TOOLCHAIN_NAME=gcc, LIB_SUFFIX=.dylib ****
===== Checking environment =====
mkdir -p /Users/armloud/desktop/omnetpp-4.2/bin
ERROR: /Users/armloud/desktop/omnetpp-4.2/bin is not in the path! You can add it by entering:
export PATH=/Users/armloud/desktop/omnetpp-4.2/bin:$PATH
make[1]: *** [check-env] Error 1
make: *** [allmodes] Error 2
```

I'm running on mac os x (lion 10.8). Can anyone help?thank you

Answer (score 1):

in your Omnetpp folder. run . setenv
Then run ur configure by ./configure

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this line

export PATH=/Users/armloud/desktop/omnetpp-4.2/bin:$PATH

in your .bashrc file

More info see this post https://superuser.com/a/147699